# Insert in parallel in Oracle

Tags: oracle, parallel-processing, sql-insert

I have a table with SQL insert statements.

```
rules_table
---------------------------------------
| rule_id | rule           | run_rule |
---------------------------------------
| 01      | INSERT INTO... | yes      |
---------------------------------------
| 02      | INSERT INTO... | no       |
---------------------------------------
| 03      | INSERT INTO... | yes      |
---------------------------------------
```

Each insert statement takes about 2-3 minutes to complete and there are a few hundred of them, each insert takes the following form:

```
INSERT INTO some_table
(column1, column2, ... column_n )
SELECT expression1, expression2, ... expression_n
FROM source_table
WHERE conditions;
```

is there a way I can run the insert statements in parallel?

Comment: What is the point in deleting and reposting the same question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31647548/pl-sql-insert-in-parallel?noredirect=1#comment51244777_31647548 And you haven't answered why do you store the insert statements in a table?

Comment: The inserts are stored in a table because today I might need to run rule_id = 01 and 03, but tomorrow I might only need to run rule_id = 02 depending on what the business wants.

Comment: The why do you hard-coded values in the INSERT statement? If your application wants to execute the insert statement, you must parameterize it. You just need to build the insert statement dynamically and pass the required values as parameters.

Comment: @LalitKumarB generating a WHERE clause in the insert's select statement dynamically would be a major undertaking, in the future this might be done, right now I just want to run these hard coded SQL statements in parallel.

Comment: @LalitKumarB my job is not to ask why it's to answer how it can be done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After all the discussions via comments [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31647548/pl-sql-insert-in-parallel?noredirect=1#comment51244777_31647548) and her[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31650235/insert-in-parallel-in-oracle)e, and that you cannot change your current design, I would suggest the only way to execute them in parallel is to use `DBMS_SCHEDULER`.

For example,

```
BEGIN
    DBMS_SCHEDULER.RUN_JOB('pkg1.proc1', false);
    DBMS_SCHEDULER.RUN_JOB('pkg2.proc2', false);
    DBMS_SCHEDULER.RUN_JOB('pkg3.proc3', false);
END;
/
```

So, you could have the required **insert statements** in respective **procedures**.

You would need to use `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` to execute the `INSERT` statements in the procedures. When you execute the above **PL/SQL block**, it will run all the procedures in **parallel**. Send the `rule_id` as an **IN** parameter to the procedure, based on the `rule_id` you could call the `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` to run the desired inserts statements.

Comment: Cool, I will give this a try.  I know this scenario is sort of painful to see, but it's what was created so I'm just going with it now.

Comment: @user2321926 It will work. The only pain is to create the procedures and write the logic for the inserts inside it :-)